# Angular // downgrade from Angular 11 to Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, npm-start

I need to enter in a project that is Angular 8.1.2 but using the command `ng serve` I get this error:

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions
> ^11.0.0-next || >=11.0.0 <12.0.0,
> but Angular version 8.1.2 was found instead.

So my solution (not working) was:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force 
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.1.2
```

But that is not working. And if I type `ng version` is still:

```
   _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.2.3
Node: 10.23.2
OS: darwin x64

Angular: undefined
... 
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.3
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.3
@angular/cli                 11.2.3
@schematics/angular          11.2.3
@schematics/update           0.1102.3
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid you have misread the error. It's saying that "There's such and such issue, because your CLI version is 8". Install version 11, and it should work. Looks like your local packages are not up-to-date, so just run `npm install`

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that's not working

Comment: Can you run `npm ls --depth=0` in your project directory, then same with global flag `npm ls -g --depth=0` and check what cli versions you have installed?